# jQuery/js- How to get Menu Name from a href based class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the menu name when user is click.

```
<a class="menu" onclick="getMenu()" href="#"> Home </a>
<a class="menu" onclick="getMenu()" href="#"> About</a>
<a class="menu" onclick="getMenu()" href="#"> Contact</a>
```

So in this function the alert name will popup.

```
function getMenu(){
 //the code declare here
alert('is click');
}
```

The expected result
Home is click / Contact is click

Comment: You have some great answers below! A few different methods shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like a jQuery method....

> You don't need the `onclick` attribute

`this` - The element used to trigger the function

`.textContent` - The text content of the element

`.trim()` - Remove white spaces

```
this.textContent.trim()
```

Element **>** text content **>** trim

```js
$('.menu').click(function(){
alert(this.textContent.trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="menu" href="#"> Home </a>
<a class="menu" href="#"> About</a>
<a class="menu" href="#"> Contact</a>
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Pass clicked element object to the function:

```
<a class="menu" onclick="getMenu(this)" href="#"> Home </a>
```

and then read `textContent` or `innerHTML` property of it:

```
function getMenu(obj) {
    alert(obj.textContent);
}
```

Also you might want to trim out white spaces around the text:

```
obj.textContent.trim();
```

Check the demo below.

```js
function getMenu(obj) {
    alert(obj.textContent.trim());
}
```

```html
<a class="menu" onclick="getMenu(this)" href="#"> Home </a>
<a class="menu" onclick="getMenu(this)" href="#"> About</a>
<a class="menu" onclick="getMenu(this)" href="#"> Contact</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like so, pass `this` (refers to current element) to your function `getMenu`, and to get content from links you can use [.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

```js
function getMenu(el) {
  alert(el.innerHTML + ' is click');  
}
```

```html
<a class="menu" onclick="getMenu(this)" href="#"> Home </a>
<a class="menu" onclick="getMenu(this)" href="#"> About</a>
<a class="menu" onclick="getMenu(this)" href="#"> Contact</a>
```

also you can use `.textContent` for get inner text, but be aware [IE lower than 9](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html/#t06) does not support it, also there is `.innerText` but [FF does not support it](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html/#t01), you can use small workaround to get inner text in all bworsers, like so

```
alert((el.innerText || el.textContent) + ' is click');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a cleaner way as you are using jQuery:

```
<a class="menu" id="1"  href="#"> Home </a>
<a class="menu" id="2"  href="#"> About</a>
<a class="menu" id="3"  href="#"> Contact</a>

<script>
$(".menu").click(function(){
    var currentId = $(this).attr("id");
    alert($.trim($("#"+currentId).text()));
});
</script>
```

```js
$(".menu").click(function(){
        var currentId = $(this).attr("id");
        alert($.trim($("#"+currentId).text()));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="menu" id="1"  href="#"> Home </a>
    <a class="menu" id="2"  href="#"> About</a>
    <a class="menu" id="3"  href="#"> Contact</a>
```